# Initialise char array with string variable in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 main()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Enter a word : ";
    cin >> word;
    int wordlen = word.length();
    cout << wordlen;
    char word_arr[wordlen] = word;
    for(int i=0;i<wordlen;i++)
    {
      cout << word_arr[i] << " " << i << endl;
    }

}
```

So basically im taking a word as input from the user and storing every character in an array.
But, thecompiler throws this error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
char word_arr[wordlen] = word;

Can someone fix this? thanks.

Comment: Why do you actually need to assign this string into array? You can easily access each character by index in `std::string` as well.

Comment: `word` is basically already an array of characters, what are you trying to achieve? Note that `char word_arr[wordlen]` where `wordlen` is not a compile time constant is not valid c++

Comment: Thank you so much r3mus! im still learning c++ so I didnt know about this function, Cheers!

Comment: Arrays are really simple and have very few features. You cannot assign to an array, for example, just to the elements in the array. You also can only initialize an array with a brace-enclosed list, or a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in the case of a `char` array.

Comment: @r3mus post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string word;
   cout << "Enter a word : ";
   cin >> word;

   int wordlen = word.length();
   cout << wordlen;

   char* word_arr = new char[wordlen+1]; // +1 needed for '\0' character
   strncpy(word_arr, word.c_str(), wordlen);

   for(int i=0;i<wordlen;i++)
      cout << word_arr[i] << " " << i << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `strncpy` gives no advantage over `strcpy` if the array has already been correctly sized